# Reusing implementation of UITextField Delegate methods

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my application I want to use a UITextField multiple times. And for each of this UITextField I want to implement the UITextFieldDelegate methods (didEndEditing, didBeginEditing, should...).

My idea was to subclass the UITextField and set the delegate to itself. Then implementing the delegate methods as I want them to be implemented. It this case I would be able to use the subclassed UITextField anywhere, and the delegate methods will be implemented once, so I won't have to implement them in every VC separately.

BUT!

Delegation is used the communicate to another object to delegate some stuff to that object. It makes no sense to set the delegate to itself.

How should I implement the delegate methods ONCE so every time I place the UITextField using Interface Builder and set the class to the custom UITextField, the textfield will behave according tot the implemented delegate methods.

Thanks for all your help

Comment: A UIView should not be it's own delegate. Make a UIViewController implement the delegate protocol and assign it as a delegate whenever you need one, as suggested by @Emilie

Comment: Allright thanks I will work on that.

Answer (score 2):

My solution might not be optimal and I'm still seeking for a better one, but has no one is answering you, here we go :

A `UIView` should never try to "control" anything : it's just a view. That's why through my projects, all my `UIViewController` inherit from a base `UIViewController` (`BaseViewController`). This `BaseViewController` has all the `UITextField` delegation code, so whenever a `UIViewController` set a `UITextField` delegate to `self`, the `BaseViewController` handles it. Because I want my `BaseViewController` to be able to control all my view's `UIScrollView` content offset, I also have a base class `BaseView` which all my `UIViews` are inheriting, that is having by default a `UIScrollview`.